# Carousel with js and css in REACT

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I created a carousel in html, css and js. The below are the respective codes.

HTML:

```
<div class="doorHardwareTile" id="dh">
  <img class="mySlidesDH slide-to-right" src="images/Folder1/1.jpg?" alt="" />
  <img class="mySlidesDH slide-to-right" src="images/Folder1/2.jpg?" alt="" />
  <img class="mySlidesDH slide-to-right" src="images/Folder1/3.jpg?" alt="" />
  <img class="mySlidesDH slide-to-right" src="images/Folder1/4.jpg?" alt="" />
  <img class="mySlidesDH slide-to-right" src="images/Folder1/5.jpg?" alt="" />
  <img class="mySlidesDH slide-to-right" src="images/Folder1/6.jpg?" alt="" />

<div class="overlayDH">
    <img src="images/Folder1/0.png?" alt="" />
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .slide-to-right {
  position: relative;
  animation: animateright 0.5s;
  }

  @keyframes animateright {
  from {
    right: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
   }
  to {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
   }
  }

 .doorHardwareTile {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 560px;
  height: 373px;
  min-width: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
 }

.mySlidesDH {
 display: none;
 }

.overlayDH {
  position: absolute;
  width: 560px;
  height: 373px;

  z-index: 800;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
 }

 .overlayDH img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  align-content: center;
}

.doorHardwareTile:hover .overlayDH {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function doorHardwareSS() {
  var myIndex = 0;
  carouselDH();

  function carouselDH() {
    var i;
    var totalElements = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlidesDH");
    for (i = 0; i < totalElements.length; i++) {
      totalElements[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > totalElements.length) {
      myIndex = 1;
    }
    totalElements[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carouselDH, 5000);
  }
});
```

This worked perfectly in the html, css and js.

However, when I tried to replicate the same in REACT. It throws error in the following line

```
totalElements[i].style.display = "none";
```

The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined."

The images that I want in the carousel are retrieved from DB in a class based component.

I'm just a beginner in REACT. I would be thankful for any help in achiving the same result.

The below is the REACT code which is called in a class based component.

```
import React from "react";

const ImageSlide = props => {
  if (
    props.imagePath === undefined ||
    props.imagePath === null ||
    props.imagePath.length === 0
  )
    return null;

  return (
    <div className={props.styles}>
      {props.imagePath.map(image => {
        const path = props.svgsArray.find(str => str.indexOf(image.hash) > 1);
        // console.log(path);
        return (
          <img
            className="mySlidesDH slide-to-right"
            key={image.id}
            src={path}
            alt={props.styles}
          />
        );
      })}
      <div className={props.styles2}>
          <img src={require("./images/1_Door_hardware/0.png?")} alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageSlide;
```

Please note that value doorHardwareTile is passed through `props.styles` and value overlayDH is passed through `props.styles2`

Comment: what the react code you wrote ?

Comment: Your code updates the real DOM, react only updates the real DOM if changes are made inside the virtual DOM and noor does React want\expect you to do this. So the approach to do this is inherently different from the code you are showing. Start with `create-react-app` because I am missing React code.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the query with the react code.

Comment: I don't see anything like `totalElements[i].style.display = "none";` in the React component code you posted. Is your app running both the React _and_ jQuery code, perhaps? I'd highly suggest porting over your jQuery code to React component logic instead.

Comment: Yes, I am combining jQuery and React. The result that I achieved in HTML, CSS and JS is very much the one that I need. I'm not sure how to port jQuery to React component logic. That's where I need help.

Answer (score 0):

For React try the following package:

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-animations

For React Native:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations

Here is an example but its for react-native it might have the same idea of how you could do a simple right slide, but still you need a function to fade out or set opacity to zero of the container, once it is slide to right and have another function to set it to its original position with replacing picture inside the container.

First set position of container inside the **this.state**:

```
this.state = {
   containerRightSlideAnim: new Animated.ValueXY({x: 0, y: 0})
}
```

And inside the **constructor** set position you would like for **X**:

```
this.containerRightSlide = Animated.timing(this.state.containerRightSlideAnim, {
      toValue: {x: 200, y: 0},
      duration: 10000,
      //speed: 0.1,
      easing: Easing.in(Easing.ease)
})
```

Make a function that triggers the right slide animation:

```
triggerRightSlide(){
 this.containerRightSlide.start();
}
```

Add inside render:

```
render() {
    const animatableRightSlideStyle = this.state.containerSlideAnim.getTranslateTransform()

    return (<View>
        <Animated.View style={[animatableRightSlideStyle]}></Animated.View>
    </View>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working prototype for Carousel with pagination in ReactJS [Live Demo here](https://codepen.io/ybeaz/pen/EdLKrj)

#### HTML

```
<h2>Prototype Carousel with pagination in ReactJS</h2>
<div id="app"></div>
```

#### JS React

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

    class Pagination extends React.Component {
        constructor( props ){
            super( props );
        }

        paginationRender = ( source, activeItem, handleEvent ) => {

            const items = source.map(( item, i ) => {
                let itemClass = 'page-item';
                if( item.id === activeItem ){
                    itemClass += ' active';
                }
                return <li key={i} className={ itemClass }>
                    <a className="page-link" href="#"
                    onClick={ e => handleEvent( e, 'clickItem', item )}>
                        { i + 1 }</a>
                </li>;
            });

            return <ul className="pagination pagination-sm justify-content-center">
                <li className="page-item">
                    <a className="page-link" href="#" 
                        onClick={e => handleEvent( e, 'prevItem', {}, items )}>Prev</a>
                </li>
                {items}
                <li className="page-item">
                    <a className="page-link" href="#"
                        onClick={e => handleEvent( e, 'nextItem', {}, items )}>Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>;
        };

        render() {
            const { itemsSrc, activeItem, handleEvent } = this.props;
            //console.info('MenuContent->render()', { source });

            return <div>{this.paginationRender( itemsSrc, activeItem, handleEvent ) }</div>;
        }
    }


    class Carousel extends React.Component {
        constructor( props ){
            super( props );
        }

        carouselRender = (  source, activeItem, handleEvent ) => {
            //console.info('Carousel->carouselRender [0]', { source, state: this.state });

             const indicators = source.map(( item, i ) => {
                let itemClass = '';
                if( item.id === activeItem ){
                    itemClass += ' active';
                }
                //console.info('Carousel->carouselRender [3]', { id: item.id, item, pageItemClass, activeItem: activeItem });
                return <li key={i} data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1" className={ itemClass }
                                 onClick={ e => handleEvent( e, 'clickItem', item )}>></li>;
            });   

            const imgs = source.map(( item, i ) => {
                let itemClass = 'carousel-item';
                if( item.id === activeItem ){
                    itemClass += ' active';
                }
                //console.info('Carousel->carouselRender [5]', { id: item.id, item, pageItemClass, activeItem: activeItem });
                return <div key={i} className={ itemClass }>
                    <img src={item.src} className="img-fluid" alt="New York" />
                </div>;
            });

            //console.info('Carousel->carouselRender [7]', { });
            return <div id="demo" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                <ul className="carousel-indicators">
                                    { indicators }
                                </ul>
                                <div className="carousel-inner">
                                    { imgs }
                                </div>
                                <a className="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon"
                                        onClick={e => handleEvent( e, 'prevItem', {}, source )}>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a className="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                                    <span className="carousel-control-next-icon"
                                        onClick={e => handleEvent( e, 'nextItem', {}, source )}>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>;
        };

        render() {
            const { itemsSrc, activeItem, handleEvent } = this.props;
            //console.info('MenuContent->render()', { source });

            return <div>{this.carouselRender( itemsSrc, activeItem, handleEvent ) }</div>;    
        }
    }

    const inputProps = {
        itemsSrc: [
                { id: 0,
                    name: 'Los Angeles',
                    level: 'basic',
                    src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg'
             },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Chicago',
                    level: 'basic',
                    src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'New York',
                    level: 'advanced',
                    src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg'
                },           
            ],
    };

    class Wrapper extends React.Component {
        constructor( props ){
            super( props );
            this.state = {
                activeItem: 0,
            };
        }

        handleEvent = ( e, actionType, item, items ) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let itemsLength, activeItem;

            switch( actionType ){
                case 'clickItem':
                    //console.info('MenuContent->paginationRender', { actionType, id: item.id, item });
                    this.setState({ activeItem: item.id });
                break;
                case 'prevItem':
                    activeItem = this.state.activeItem;
                    if ( activeItem === 0  ){
                        break;
                    }
                    activeItem -= 1;
                    this.setState({ activeItem });
                break;
                case 'nextItem':
                    itemsLength = items.length;
                    activeItem = this.state.activeItem;
                    if (activeItem === itemsLength -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    activeItem += 1;
                    this.setState({ activeItem });
                break;
            }
            //console.info('MenuContent->handleEvent()', { actionType, item, items });

        }

        render(){
            let props = this.props;
            const { activeItem } = this.state;
            props = { ...props, handleEvent: this.handleEvent, activeItem };

            return <div className="App">

                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-1">
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-10">

                            <Pagination { ...props }/>
                            <Carousel { ...props }/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>;
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper {  ...inputProps }/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```